# Как присвоить постоянное значение для новых записей в триггере?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

В БД нужно после добавления новой записи заменять значение в колонке на 0.

Родил следующий триггер при помощи гугла:

```
create or replace trigger AutoDisabled
  after insert on SCHEMA."Reason" for each row
begin
  :new. "AutoEnabled" := 0;
end;
```

При выполнении триггер намертво повесил Toad.

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: На счет toad не знаю, но модифицировать поле может только `before` триггер, а не `after`. Хотя ни к каким повисаниям то конечно приводить не должно, просто выдавать ошибку

Answer (score 2):

> Что я сделал не так?

- в коде триггера допустили синтаксические ошибки
- проигнорировали сообщения компилятора об ошибках
- не обратились за помощью к [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B).

При выполнении вставки должна была появится следующая ошибка :

> SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'ME.AUTODISABLED' is invalid and failed re-validation

Если бы были учтены упомянутые выше пункты, получилось бы следующее:

```
create or replace trigger AutoDisabled
    before insert on me."Reason" for each row
begin
    :new."AutoEnabled" := 0;
end;
/
Trigger AUTODISABLED compiled

insert into "Reason" values ('Reason name 1', null) 
/

1 row inserted.
```